# Select rows with a specific date

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, compare

I'm sending the variable "lasttime" via POST to my PHP script. This variable contains a timestamp as a string. In my MySQL database I have a column 'time'. This column has the type 'TIMESTAMP' and by updating the current timestamp is entered.

I want to select all rows from the database which have a timestamp after the timestamp in the variable $lasttime.

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) > '$lasttime'
```

The problem is, that all rows are returned. How can I fix that?

Comment: Please show examples of what `time` and `$lasttime` look like.  You should do so by editing the question.

Comment: $lasttime is for example `1397855585`
And the value in the database is e.g. `2014-04-18 19:01:07`

Comment: The way you have quotes around `$lasttime`, I think you are comparing the date to the literal string '$lasttime', and not the value it represents.

Comment: What part of "you should do so by editing the question" was confusing?

Comment: @Jerry MySQL will convert between strings and numbers as necessary.

Comment: but the string literal $lasttime will always evaluate to zero.

Comment: I have tried only `$lasttime` now. --> There isn't any row selected...

Comment: Can you show more of the PHP? We need to see how you're quoting the query and how you're submitting it.

Comment: @Jerry The variable will be replaced with its value by PHP, assuming the query is in doublequotes.

Comment: @Barmar - true enough. I wasn't ready to assume that from the context.

Comment: `$abfrage = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) > $lasttime";
$ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))
{
   $id = $row->id;
   
   echo $id . "<br>";
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed it now to

`$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $lasttime); SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE timediff('$time',time) < 0`

and it works fine...

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing in $lasttime a string formatted datetime (e.g. 2014-04-19 03:04:05), you have first to normalized it to unixtime: `$unixtime = strtotime($lasttime)`
Then the sql query will look like `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(time) > $unixtime`

Comment: The value from the database is a string.  The value in `$lasttime` is a number.

Comment: I have tried `$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $lasttime);
$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE time > '$time'";` But it did not work too...

Comment: Are your php & mysql instances working with the same timezone? Is the time in both of them synched?

Comment: Yes, it's the same timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to do it this way?
`$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $lasttime);
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE timediff('$time',time) > 0`

`time` is the column in the database.

Comment: I've tried it just now and it's the same result... all rows are returned. :-(